# How to get detailed error for ValueError: {'code': -32016, 'data': 'Reverted', 'message': 'The execution failed due to an exception.'}

Tags: web3js, smart-contract-wallets, kovan

I deployed my Fund_me smart contract on Kovan testnet and I tried to call the withdraw function on it using web3, but I'm getting the error ValueError: {'code': -32016, 'data': 'Reverted', 'message': 'The execution failed due to an exception.'}.
How can I troubleshoot this or get a more detailed error of what's wrong?
Here's the contract withdraw method:

```
 modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    _;
}

function withdraw() public payable onlyOwner {
    msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance);

    for (
        uint256 funderIndex = 0;
        funderIndex < funders.length;
        funderIndex++
    ) {
        address funder = funders[funderIndex];
        addressToAmountFunded[funder] = 0;
    }
    funders = new address[](0);
}
```

Here's the web3 code to invoke the withdraw method on the contract:

```
web3 = Web3(
    Web3.HTTPProvider("https://kovan.infura.io/v3/api_key")
)
abi = '[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_priceFeed","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"addressToAmountFunded","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"fund_Catherine","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"funders","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"ethAmount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getConversionRate","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"getEntranceFee","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"getPrice","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"getVersion","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"priceFeed","outputs":[{"internalType":"contract AggregatorV3Interface","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"withdraw","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"}]'
addr = "0xAAa9F30a71456aFB436dDF49BaA12952F5116017"
modelcontract = web3.eth.contract(address=addr, abi=abi)
tx = modelcontract.functions.withdraw().buildTransaction()
tx.update({"from": str(account)})
tx.update({"to": addr})
tx.update({"gas": 21000})
tx.update({"gasPrice": 2})
nonce = web3.eth.get_transaction_count(str(account))
print(nonce)
tx.update({"nonce": nonce})
signed_message = web3.eth.account.sign_message(
    tx, private_key=config["wallets"]["from_key"]
tx_hash = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_message.rawTransaction)
tx_receipt = web3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash, 180)
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong or how can I get the detailed error message?
I verified that the account address matches the owner address of the contract as well.

Comment: Can you include all your smart contract code?

Comment: I dont see the parameter "value", you add in your function "withdraw" the modifier "payable" but in your file web3 you don't set the param value with price.